# Instantiate a class template with another class template leads to using incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say, we have the following class templates:

```
template<size_t S>
struct A
{
  char str[S];
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
  T t;

public:
  void init(); // Should initialize the 't' member in some a way.
};
```

Now, if I specialize the `init` with some non-template types as parameter of the `B` template, it's OK. But, I can not specialize it with the `A` as the parameter of the `B` without specifying its `S` value. I.e., I'd like to do something like this:

```
template<>
void B<A<S>>::init()
{
  // Initialize the 't.str'. For example:
  memset(t.str, 0, S);
}
```

Comment: An `init` function is kind of an anti-pattern.  The constructor for `B` should initializer all of its members, and ideally all of its members should be RAII types so the defaults work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

To provide a partial specialization, that performs something specific to `B<A<???>>`, you need to actually provide such a partial specialization for the class:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t S>
struct A
{
  char str[S];
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
  T t;

public:
  void init(); // Should initialize the 't' member in some a way.
};

template<std::size_t S>
class B<A<S>> {
  using T = A<S>;

  T t;

public:
  void init(); // Should initialize the 't' member in some a way.
};

template<std::size_t S>
void B<A<S>>::init()
{
  // Initialize the 't.str'. For example:
  std::memset(t.str, 0, S);
  std::cout << "Initialized B<A<" << S << ">>\n";
}

int main() {
    B<A<3>> b;
    b.init();
}
```

Note that there are two key differences to your code:

1. There is a partial specialization of the class template `template<std::size_t S> class B<A<S>>`
2. The `init` member function of that class template can now be defined as `template<std::size_t> void B<A<S>>::init() { /* ... */ }`

You can omit the base case definition of the class template `B` and replace it with `template<typename T> class B;` if no other instantiation is valid in your use case.

[see it live](https://godbolt.org/z/ljNYpQ)

Answer (score 0):

Since struct `A` should be responsible for construction and destruction of its members, I suggest you doing the following:

```cpp
template <size_t S = 5>
struct A {
    A() {
        memset(str, 0, S);
    }

    char str[S];
};
```

and then you can have:

```cpp
template<>
void B<A<>>::init()
{}
```

**UPDATE**

As @NathanOliver pointed out, default constructor for struct `A` is not even needed. Following would work too:

```cpp
template <size_t S = 5>
struct A {
    char str[S]{};
};
```

and, since responsibility of initializing the `char` array is passed to struct `A`, you do **not** need template specialization.

Comment: Why even have an empty `init` function?  Also, use `char str[S]{};` and you don't need a default constructor in `A`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I left empty `init` function so that OP can place there something else maybe... and yes, you are right regarding the default ctor which is not needed. I will updated my answer. Tnx

Comment: I placed an essential of my issue here. I know that I can move the initialization to the `A`. Exactly, in my project the `B` template is more complicated and its `T` parameter is expected to be a POD struct.